# How to use valgrind with lock-free data structures?

Tags: valgrind, lock-free

I'm experimenting with lock-free structures in the liblfds library (http://www.liblfds.org/) with an eye towards using them in a toolchain that also incorporates valgrind for various error checks, which is causing me some trouble.  I built a debug version of the library and used it to compile the following program:

```
#include <liblfds.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static void *
handler(void *arg)
{
  struct queue_state *queue = (struct queue_state *)arg;
  const char *message;
  int result = queue_dequeue(queue, (void **)&message);
  assert(0 != result);
  printf("%s\n", message);
  return NULL;
}

int
main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  struct queue_state *queue;
  int result = queue_new(&queue, 1);
  assert(0 != result);
  pthread_t thread;
  result = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, handler, queue);
  assert(0 == result);
  result = queue_guaranteed_enqueue(queue, (void *)"Hello lock free queue!");
  assert(0 != result);
  result = pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  assert(0 == result);
}
```

This program runs fine when executed from the command line, but has problems when run under valgrind.  memcheck reports jumps that depend on uninitialized values, and both DRD and helgrind cause the program to fail when the child thread attempts to dequeue the value (queue_dequeue returns 0, tripping the assert).  I can work around the memcheck reports but the DRD and helgrind crashes are a show stopper.

I'm sure that getting this working will require that I insert some of the client request macros, but the documentation for the thread error checker macros is oriented towards mutex structures other than those provided by pthread and also the handling of memory from custom allocators.  I'm hoping for a pointer to information provided by someone who has worked on (and maybe solved) this problem before I go digging into the guts of valgrind to figure out how/if this can be made to work.

Comment: The thread is starting and running queue_dequeue() *before* you enqueue the element; queue_dequeue() does not block.  That should be fine - dequeue should just return NULL - but then printf() will not be happy.

Answer (score 0):

You could always ask the library author on the site forum :-)

Last I knew, valgrind passed release 6 with no warnings, so your experience is unexpected.

Drop me an email - admim at liblfds dot org.